# Classic Thesis 4.6 doesn't compile

Tags: compiling, classicthesis, compilation-error, prelim2e

I have `TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2020/W32TeX) kpathsea version 6.3.2` on my pc.
I downloaded Classic Thesis .zip from CTAN

When I try to compile ClassicThesis.tex in Texstudio with the standard pdflatex command I get these errors:

```
Output routine didn't use all of \box255. \include{FrontBackmatter/DirtyTitlepage}
Output routine didn't use all of \box255. \begin{titlepage}
Output routine didn't use all of \box255. \end{titlepage}
Output routine didn't use all of \box255. \include{FrontBackmatter/Titleback}
Output routine didn't use all of \box255. ...lepage\include{FrontBackmatter/Dedication}
Output routine didn't use all of \box255. \cleardoublepage
Output routine didn't use all of \box255. ...ublepage\include{FrontBackmatter/Abstract}
Output routine didn't use all of \box255. \cleardoublepage
Output routine didn't use all of \box255. ...page\include{FrontBackmatter/Publications}
Output routine didn't use all of \box255. \cleardoublepage
Output routine didn't use all of \box255. ...e\include{FrontBackmatter/Acknowledgments}
Output routine didn't use all of \box255. \cleardoublepage
Output routine didn't use all of \box255. \clearpage
Output routine didn't use all of \box255. ...ublepage\include{FrontBackmatter/Contents}
Output routine didn't use all of \box255. \part{Some Kind of Manual}
Output routine didn't use all of \box255. \part{Some Kind of Manual}
Output routine didn't use all of \box255. \item N
Output routine didn't use all of \box255. \item\texttt
Output routine didn't use all of \box255. \clearpage
Output routine didn't use all of \box255. \end{itemize}
Output routine didn't use all of \box255. F
Output routine didn't use all of \box255.
Output routine didn't use all of \box255. \include{Chapters/Chapter01}
Output routine didn't use all of \box255. \cleardoublepage
Output routine didn't use all of \box255. \part{The Showcase}
Output routine didn't use all of \box255. \part{The Showcase}
Output routine didn't use all of \box255.
Output routine didn't use all of \box255.
Output routine didn't use all of \box255. \include{Chapters/Chapter02}
Output routine didn't use all of \box255. \include{Chapters/Chapter02}
Output routine didn't use all of \box255. T
Output routine didn't use all of \box255. \include{Chapters/Chapter03}
Output routine didn't use all of \box255. \part{Appendix}
Output routine didn't use all of \box255. \part{Appendix}
Output routine didn't use all of \box255. \include{Chapters/Chapter0A}
Output routine didn't use all of \box255. \cleardoublepage
Output routine didn't use all of \box255. ...page\include{FrontBackmatter/Declaration}
Output routine didn't use all of \box255. \cleardoublepage
Output routine didn't use all of \box255. ...blepage\include{FrontBackmatter/Colophon}
Using fall-back BibTeX(8) backend:(biblatex) functionality may be reduced/unavailable.
Non standard sectioning command \section(titlesec) detected. Using default spacing and no format.
Non standard sectioning command \subsection(titlesec) detected. Using default spacing and no format.
Non standard sectioning command \subsubsection(titlesec) detected. Using default spacing and no format.
Non standard sectioning command \paragraph(titlesec) detected. Using default spacing and no format.
Non standard sectioning command \subparagraph(titlesec) detected. Using default spacing and no format.
Usage of package `tocloft' together(scrreprt) with a KOMA-Script class is not recommended.
No file ClassicThesis.bbl.
No file ClassicThesis1-blx.bbl.
Overfull \hbox (190.74121pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
Overfull \hbox (190.74121pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
Overfull \hbox (190.74121pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
Overfull \hbox (190.74121pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
Overfull \hbox (190.74121pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
Overfull \hbox (190.74121pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
Overfull \hbox (190.74121pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
Overfull \hbox (190.74121pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
Empty bibliography
Overfull \hbox (1.76471pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (190.74121pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
Overfull \hbox (190.74121pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
Citation 'knuth:1974' on page 11 undefined
Citation 'knuth:1974' on page 11 undefined
Overfull \hbox (190.74121pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
Overfull \hbox (190.74121pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
Overfull \hbox (190.74121pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
Overfull \hbox (190.74121pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
Overfull \hbox (190.74121pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
Overfull \hbox (190.74121pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
Citation 'bringhurst:2002' on page 3 undefined
Citation 'bringhurst:2002' on page 3 undefined
Overfull \hbox (41.68665pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (190.74121pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
Overfull \hbox (190.74121pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
Overfull \hbox (190.74121pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
Overfull \hbox (190.74121pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
Overfull \hbox (6.3659pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (0.29587pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (2.07549pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (2.07549pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (190.74121pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
Overfull \hbox (190.74121pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
Overfull \hbox (190.74121pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
Overfull \hbox (190.74121pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
Overfull \hbox (190.74121pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
Overfull \hbox (190.74121pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
Citation 'taleb:2012' on page 13 undefined
Citation 'taleb:2012' on page 13 undefined
Citation 'ferriss:2016' on page 13 undefined
Citation 'greenwald:2014' on page 13 undefined
Citation 'adams:2013' on page 13 undefined
Citation 'pausch:2008' on page 13 undefined
Citation 'aurelius:2002' on page 13 undefined
Citation 'adams:1996' on page 13 undefined
Citation 'trump:1987' on page 13 undefined
Citation 'feynman:1985' on page 13 undefined
Citation 'cialdini:1984' on page 13 undefined
Citation 'seneca' on page 13 undefined
Citation 'orwell:1949' on page 13 undefined
Citation 'taleb:2010' on page 13 undefined
Citation 'munger:2008' on page 13 undefined
Citation 'postman:2005' on page 13 undefined
Citation 'harari:2014' on page 13 undefined
Citation 'peterson:2018' on page 13 undefined
Citation 'taleb:2018' on page 13 undefined
Citation 'frankl:1959' on page 13 undefined
Overfull \hbox (24.50685pt too wide) in paragraph
Overfull \hbox (190.74121pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
Citation 'bentley:1999' on page 14 undefined
Citation 'bentley:1999' on page 14 undefined
Citation 'cormen:2001' on page 14 undefined
Citation 'cormen:2001' on page 14 undefined
Overfull \hbox (9.19788pt too wide) in paragraph
Citation 'dueck:trio' on page 14 undefined
Citation 'dueck:trio' on page 14 undefined
Citation 'knuth:1976' on page 14 undefined
Citation 'knuth:1976' on page 14 undefined
Overfull \hbox (190.74121pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
Citation 'sommerville:1992' on page 15 undefined
Citation 'sommerville:1992' on page 15 undefined
Citation 'knuth:1976' on page 15 undefined
Overfull \hbox (24.44958pt too wide) in alignment
Citation 'knuth:1976' on page 15 undefined
Citation 'knuth:1976' on page 15 undefined
Overfull \hbox (190.74121pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
Overfull \hbox (190.74121pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
Overfull \hbox (190.74121pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
Overfull \hbox (190.74121pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
Overfull \hbox (190.74121pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
Overfull \hbox (190.74121pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
Overfull \hbox (190.74121pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
Overfull \hbox (190.74121pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
Empty bibliography
Overfull \hbox (190.74121pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
Overfull \hbox (190.74121pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
Overfull \hbox (190.74121pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
There were undefined references.
Please (re)run BibTeX on the file(s):(biblatex) ClassicThesis1-blx(biblatex) ClassicThesis(biblatex) and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

I can't find the solution. Note that the other examples, `classicthesis-arsclassica-book`, `classicthesis-cv`, `classicthesis-book`, `classicthesis-article`, compile without problems.

Comment: Please provide the actual compilation log instead of the filtered log from the editor.

Comment: the problem is the prelim2e package. It is not compatible with the new latex. As far as I know an update should appear soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The prelim2e package is currently not compatible with latex, but an update is in preparation.

As a work-around:
The classicthesis-config.tex contains a setting `drafting=true`. Remove this, then prelim2e will not be loaded and then it should work.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{
  drafting=true,    % <--- remove this
```

Answer (score 6):

I just uploaded a new version of prelim2e to CTAN, so it's a matter of time until you can download it via your distribution.

The development repository can now be found here: https://github.com/TeXhackse/prelim2e
in case you can't wait that long.

Comment: A friendly quack! `:)`

Comment: I just updated my TeX Live Utility and now the compilation works!